# A problem in counting and iterating the excel lines using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, output, row, openpyxl

I have a excel file which have 590 rows.I have a weird problem where I cant find the max number of rows in this excel and somehow my row count starts at 343.
Below is my code :

```
def parseExcelFile(excelFilePath):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excelFilePath)
    sheet = wb.active
    m_row = sheet.max_row
    print("m_row ",m_row)
    for k in range(1, m_row + 1):
         print ("k ",k)
```

Expected output :

```
m_row 590
k 1
k 2
.........
```

But Actual output is :

```
k 343
k 344
.........
```

and m_row is not even getting printed. Why I am getting that output??

Comment: Works for me on a test file, so possibly a problem with your input file?

Comment: There was problem in the output console which was not able to show enough lines.

Answer (score 2):

Are you shure your output window has room for all the output?

Try setting m_row to 10 and se if it prints the expected data.

Comment: you are right. The problem is with the output console.